# Populating CKEditor's dialog with ajax AND getting response, too

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, html-object

I have a peculiar problem that has to do with CKEditor's dialog. I've managed to embed a php file (containing Datatables) into the dialog window. User can then select a row that will be inserted into CKEditor.

Embedding HTML into dialog window seemed easy:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'tableDialog', function( editor ) {
    return {
        title: 'parametres',
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 500,
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab-basic',
                label: 'Basic Settings',
                elements: [
                    {
                    type:"html",
                    id:"htmlPreview",
                    style:"width:95%;height:95%;",
                    html:test_HTML,
                        commit: function( element ) {
etc..
```

what's funny is, that populating the variable 'test_HTML' is tricky. Defining it as HTML object works perfectly:

```
test_HTML = '<object type="text/html" data="http://entseditor.etest.ee/edit/mm_insert.php" style="width:100%; height:100%"><p></p></object>';
```

, doing it with jQuery ajax will fail:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://entseditor.etest.ee/edit/mm_insert.php",
  //type: "POST",
  //data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) {
  //$("#asdasd").html( msg );
    test_HTML =  msg ;
  //alert( 'success' + test_HTML );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

(Request is good and gives proper response into id='asdasd', but CKEditor dialog window says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined". And still both HTMLs seem identical.)

Now there'd be no problem using the object, but then I can't seem to get the response from created #document. I've tried variables and hidden fields, but they are not accessible from the 'parent' document..

Does anybody have experience with this side of CKEditor?

(I'm sorry if I'm not explaining everything in proper terms..)

Comment: Well, the ugly solution is, of course, to store the variable in a cookie (as I should've known), so problem solved. But I still hope that there is a beautiful solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to get the big picture, but it kind of feels like a sync/async issue. Are you accessing the variable surely after it's set? Even if `request.done` function is declared before `CKEDITOR.dialog.add` the actual `test_HTML =  msg ;` might be getting called after `CKEDITOR.dialog.add` is ran due to it being an async call.

Meaning that while ajax is loading JavaScript keeps running along and performs `CKEDITOR.dialog.add` so that `test_HTML` remains undefined. Try to set it to a default value that is 100% surely set before any code accesses it and maby try to follow the flow in which order you code is performed.

Comment: Damn you Nenotlep :) You were absolutely right! I thought I'd checked and indeed, my test_HTML sometimes was set, and sometimes not, so that was the problem. Nevertheless, the Dialog acts funny, because (with exactly the same HTML) it now gives me instead of charAt error, an errorless gibberish of _id="cke_126_uiElement" class="cke_dialog_ui_html" style="width:95%; height:95%"_. Unfortunately I don't have time to figure it out, and the cookie approach works, but I'm sure it would be solvable the way you point out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to be of help! I can't say on the new error but hopefully it'll work :)